# Get the min. value of the many rows in query

Tags: php, mysql

Its a little bit complicated, but I will try to explain as best as I can.

I got 3 tables with news data, every table as a 'date' column that contains an unix time of the posted news.

Now select all of 'date' (from 3 tables) as get the min. value of the year using PHP date: (`date('Y', $year)`).

More informations:

Table1(Table2, Table3) -> has some 'date' column.

Now I need to withdraw those `date` fields (for example) into array, so the array will look like this: `array('1323433261', '1323424614', '1322454677', ...etc);` and then select the min. value in the array.

Hope you understand what I'm trying to reach, in case if you don't, please comment.

Comment: We're going to need the table structure with PK/FKs.

Comment: Not quite sure what you're trying to achieve. Are you just trying to get the minimum (earliest) date value from three columns, one in each of three tables?

Comment: try order by in the query based on the time

Comment: @liquorvicar Yeah. I need to get the minimum (earliest) 'date' value from three columns and display the result in one field.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this

```
SELECT MIN(min) FROM (
  (SELECT YEAR(FROM_UNIXTIME(MIN(add_date))) as min FROM table1) 
  UNION 
  (SELECT YEAR(FROM_UNIXTIME(MIN(add_date))) as min FROM table2) 
  UNION 
  (SELECT YEAR(FROM_UNIXTIME(MIN(add_date))) as min FROM table3)
) as t
```